# BEGINNER-- Doubts on why a has_and_belong_to_many association is only working one way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm learning ruby on rails and this is my first question in SO. I'm making a DB to manage products. In part of my squema I have users that can have many brands, and brands that can have many users. So my squema looks like this:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  .
  .
  .
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :brands
  .
  .
  .
end
```

---

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160614163029) do

  create_table "brands", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "brands_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "brand_id"
  end

  add_index "brands_users", ["brand_id"], name: "index_brands_users_on_brand_id"
  add_index "brands_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_brands_users_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",             default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",         default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

So when I create and user it has to put the name of his brand so I can create a brand associated to that user.

```
user.brands.create(name: "Boo")
```

This creates the association of the user with the brand so I can call user.brands and it gives me "Boo". My problem is that when I call:

```
brand.users
```

I get

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

I thought the association of this two objects should be automatic I have been searching but I don't know what I'm missing. Do I need to make manually the association from that brand to the user?

Thanks

Comment: Could you try `brand = users.brands.create(name: "Boo"); brand.reload`?

Comment: Hey Leito, I tried, but no results.   2.3.1 :040 > brand.reload
               Brand Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE "brands"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Brand id: 1, name: "Lorem ipsum", created_at: "2016-06-14 16:54:49", updated_at: "2016-06-14 16:54:49">
      2.3.1 :041 > brand.users           
           User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "brands_users" ON "users"."id" = "brands_users"."user_id" WHERE "brands_users"."brand_id" = ?  [["brand_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
2.3.1 :042 >

Comment: Sorry for the format!

Comment: Dont worry about the format, I don't see the SQL for the create. Please paste the output of both lines.You can also add it to the original question, as additional  info useful for other answerers.

Comment: Hey! I was doing all over again to copy the code and now it magically works! Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: If you can recall what change, post it as an answer to you own question to help others. I"m glad you make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Reloading console fixed the issue. And now it works like I wanted:

```
2.3.1 :001 > user = User.second
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
=> #<User id: 2, name: "Luis Hirthe DVM", email: "example-1@example.org", created_at: "2016-06-14 16:52:17", updated_at: "2016-06-14 16:52:17">

2.3.1 :002 > user.brands.create(name: "Foo")
(0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "brands" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Foo"], ["created_at", "2016-06-14 20:23:08.410200"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-14 20:23:08.410200"]]
SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "brands_users" ("user_id", "brand_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 2], ["brand_id", 1]]
(0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<Brand id: 1, name: "Foo", created_at: "2016-06-14 20:23:08", updated_at: "2016-06-14 20:23:08">

2.3.1 :003 > brand = Brand.first
Brand Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "brands".* FROM "brands"  ORDER BY "brands"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Brand id: 1, name: "Foo", created_at: "2016-06-14 20:23:08", updated_at: "2016-06-14 20:23:08">

2.3.1 :004 > brand.users.all
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "brands_users" ON "users"."id" = "brands_users"."user_id" WHERE "brands_users"."brand_id" = ?  [["brand_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<User id: 2, name: "Luis Hirthe DVM", email: "example-1@example.org", created_at: "2016-06-14 16:52:17", updated_at: "2016-06-14 16:52:17">
```

I hope this relationship example help other beginners.